# If $A \in M_n(\Bbb{C})$ and $\det(A^k+I)=1$ for all $k \lt 2^n$, $k\in \Bbb{N}$, then $A$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

This is an unsolved problem in my school. Many tried to find out a solution but failed.
I think it almost equals to proving that if $(\lambda^k_1+1)(\lambda_2^k+1)\dots(\lambda_n^k+1)=1$ is true for all $k\in \Bbb{N}$, then every $\lambda_i$ is zero. But I have no clue how to proceed.

Sorry for my poor English. Anything ambiguous I'll clear it up. Thanks in advance for any hint.